# How do I make a list date column turn mint green if the date entered is within the last 12 months and turn light red if it outside of 12 months?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a list made that tracks several employee training dates. We are currently entering the date they last tested/trained. Trainings are due every 12 months or every 36 months.

How can I make the date changed to light red if not within the past 12 months and mint green if it was within the last 12 months?

Needs to be a rolling 12 months from todays date not a set date where I have to continuously change the timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint JSON column formatting for your requirements. Use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "padding-left": "10px",
    "color": "=if(Number(@currentField) != 0,'white','')",
    "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) != 0,if(@currentField < addDays(@now,-365),'#ff0000','#00a170'),'')"
  }
}
```

You can find steps to apply JSON column formatting at: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Here I have used `Number(@currentField) != 0` to check if SharePoint date column is blank or not. You can find other ways to check if SharePoint date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/).

You can also use **internal name** of date column in format like `[$TrainingDate]` in place of `@currentField`. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]